# sql how to select the next to last row of the groups with two or more rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table of performed actions over different object instances that have different versions. If I group the actions per instance and version, with this SELECT (abbreviated)

```
SELECT instance, version, COUNT(id) AS cnt
FROM actions
WHERE status=0
  AND version IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY instance, version
```

I obtain this table (abbreviated)

```
 instance | version | cnt 
----------+---------+------
  1021    | 18.1    | 263   
  1021    | 18.2    | 422  
  1021    | 19.1    | 949  
  1191    | 18.2    | 28
  1195    | 18.1    | 584  
  1195    | 18.2    | 176
  1195    | 18.3    | 437
  1195    | 19.1    | 152
  1195    | 19.2    | 545  
  1195    | 19.3    | 399
  1196    | 18.3    | 844 
  1196    | 19.1    | 800 
  1197    | 18.3    | 2 
  1201    | 18.1    | 471
  1201    | 18.2    | 584
  1201    | 18.3    | 553
  1201    | 19.1    | 498
  1201    | 19.2    | 203
  1201    | 19.3    | 36
  1208    | 18.1    | 444
  1208    | 18.2    | 548
  1208    | 18.3    | 31
  1208    | 19.2    | 357
  1210    | 19.1    | 514
  1211    | 18.2    | 341
  1211    | 19.1    | 531
  ....
```

now, I want the row corresponding to the previous to the last version for the instances that have more than one version.

So, in the example, I need to select the rows

```
 instance | version | cnt 
----------+---------+------
  1021    | 18.2    | 422  
  1195    | 19.2    | 545  
  1196    | 18.3    | 844 
  1201    | 19.2    | 203
  1208    | 18.3    | 31
  1211    | 18.2    | 341
  ...
```

I have tried `GROUP BY instance HAVING count(*) >= 2` to begin by filtering the results, but it counts the original rows, not the resulting rows after the first `GROUP BY instance, version`.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not using a `MAX(version)` ? You don't need to `GROUP BY` it. The `HAVING count(*) >= 2` works for `cnt>2` (the `count(*)`), you can just test it modifing the count(*)>=400 to check that only retrieve the `cnt>400`

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: @Roy I don't need the MAX(version) I need the previous version to the last version for each instance that has more than two versions.

Comment: @Akina MariaDB version 10.4.10

Comment: If you only have 1 version do you want it or not?

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that abbreviated results are stored in temp table test. Following query will give you the expected output.

```
select * from test where (instance,version)in
(select instance,max(version) as version from test A where exists 
(select max(version) as version from test B where A.instance=B.instance and A.version<B.version group by instance) group by instance)
```

Ouput

```
instance version cnt
1021      18.2   422
1195      19.2   545
1196      18.3   844
1201      19.2   203
1208      18.3   31
1211      18.2   341
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need (no optimization!)

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT instance, version, COUNT(id) AS cnt
          FROM actions
          WHERE status=0
            AND version IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY instance, version ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT instance, MAX(version) version
          FROM cte1
          GROUP BY instance ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT instance, MAX(version) version
          FROM cte1
          LEFT JOIN cte2 USING (instance, version)
          WHERE cte2.instance IS NULL
          GROUP BY instance )
SELECT cte1.*
FROM cte1
JOIN cte3 USING (instance, version)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=327cbe65295a7515e8aae7df4b897cde)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT iv.*
FROM (SELECT instance, version, COUNT(id) AS cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY instance ORDER BY version DESC) as seqnum
      FROM actions
      WHERE status = 0 AND
            version IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY instance, version
     ) iv
WHERE seqnum = 2;
```